# How to disable velocity logs

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, velocity

I've been trying to disable Velocity logs, and the only way I've found so far with positive results is to set:

```
runtime.log.logsystem.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem
```

but inside the velocity.properties that resides inside the velocity.jar.

I'm using velocity in a Web Application (tomcat) context. Is there any way to disable the velocity (by setting the previous property or whatever) BUT without modifying the JAR??

Cannot modify any CODE

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your application logging properties

Comment: I just have a log4j.properties with nothing regarding velocity inside of it

Answer (score 18):

**In general**: just add following line to your `velocity.properties` :

```
runtime.log.logsystem.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogChute
```

**To your question**:
It depends on how the velocity engine is loaded. Is it possible to give it a custom `velocity.properties` file? 
For example Solr's `VelocityResponseWriter` has such property called `v.properties` (or `init.properties.file` in current versions). 
Look, if the method `org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.init(Properties)` is called somewhere in the code...

Comment: Any idea how to do this from the command line, like using a system property? Doing something like `java -Druntime.log.logsystem.class...` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think velocity itself is not reading system properties to update its configuration @santon

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can configure desired logging in `velocity`:

```
//java configuration
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS, "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute" );
ve.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger","velocity");

//log4j properties
log4j.category.velocity=WARN
```

IMHO `INFO` is fine with `velocity` as on startup you will notice some useful velocity engine configuration details, but during templating nothing specific comes out from `INFO` level.

Comment: cannot touch the code (sorry if I forgot that detail, I will edit the question)

Comment: Also, I read the Velocity [documentation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#Configuring_Logging)

Answer (score 3):

You can implement the method VelocityEngine engine()  of VelocityBuilder interface and then specify a file you want use as follow:

```
    public VelocityEngine engine() {
                if(engine == null) {
                    engine = new VelocityEngine();

                    Properties properties = new Properties();
                    InputStream in = null;
                    try {
//here is where you specify the filename "/WEB-INF/velocity.properties"
                        in = webApplicationContext.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/velocity.properties");
                        properties.load(in);
                        engine.init(properties);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        logger.error("Error loading velocity engine properties");
                        throw new ProgramException("Cannot load velocity engine properties");
                    }

                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
                }

                return engine;
            }
```

And after in your velocity.properties file:

```
resource.loader = framework

framework.resource.loader.description = Framework Templates Resource Loader
framework.resource.loader.class = applica.framework.library.velocity.WEBINFResourceLoader

webapp.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.WebappLoader
webapp.resource.loader.path =
runtime.log.logsystem.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem
file.resource.loader.description = Velocity File Resource Loader
file.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
file.resource.loader.path =

class.resource.loader.description = Velocity Classpath Resource Loader
class.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
```

Answer (score 2):

```
VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class", NullLogChute.class.getName());
velocityEngine.init();
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain your answer, it would make it more valuable.