# What is velocity.log file for Apache Cayenne?

Tags: java, velocity, apache-cayenne

I noticed that Apache Velocity is always writing logs to a file "velocity.log". Do we actually need this? How do I turn this off (disable velocity.log output)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have to checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443366/how-to-disable-velocity-logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Cayenne](https://cayenne.apache.org/) is using velocity as a template engine:

> Cayenne supports database reverse engineering and generation, as well
>   as a Velocity-based class generation engine.

Velocity property file is inside `CayenneModeler.jar`

```
cayenne-3.1.1\bin\CayenneModeler.jar\org\apache\velocity\runtime\defaults\velocity.properties
```

You can change log by updating `runtime.log = velocity.log`